# How to download data anonymously?

Tags: privacy, anonymity

How to download data anonymously, were to store the data. I was reading a post on a forum and a guy was asking how do you download data anonymously and he asked how do hackers do it ,everybody started to be smart but nobody did know how. So my question is how to download data anonymously and how do hackers do it?

P.S. Please don't tell me to use a BitTorrent or similar because they are traceable and hackers don't use them.

Comment: what are you trying to download? might want to be more specific

Comment: The obvious answer is TOR. When that doesn't fit your requirements, you should describe them more clearly.

Comment: Your question should be more specific. But as Adnan and others answer using Tail, VPN and Proxy servers is a solution but I'm sure that it's possible to track your works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something sufficiently safe and user-friendly, I suggest downloading a copy of [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) then burning it on a DVD or USB stick. Whenever you want to access the Internet anonymously and/or download some files, simply plug/insert it in your computer and boot from it. The most important features of Tails are:

> - Use the Internet anonymously and circumvent censorship.
> - All connections to the Internet are forced to go through the Tor
>     network.
> - Leave no trace on the computer you are using unless you ask it
>     explicitly.
> - Use state-of-the-art cryptographic tools to encrypt your files,
>     emails and instant messaging.

Tails uses Tor and a securely-configured browser to achieve a high level of anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

You're not very specific here, but in general this should work:
Visit some place with open wireless access.
Connect to it, and start downloading.
If you really want to hide, change your mac address before you connect.

Answer (score 0):

While Tor would be the ideal option, it tends to be quite slow.

You could use VPN services to secure your connection as well, [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com) is a commercial service that gives you an encrypted connection and performs no logging (or so they say) if you're will to pay a monthly rate for the service. There are non-commercial services also available but they're quite flakey. [VPN Book](http://www.vpnbook.com) is one such free service.